# Changing Azure role configuration setting does not restart app domain?

Tags: azure

I use SquishIt to bundle my scripts and such, so there is some code that runs at app startup that configures the bundle using a base URL specified in the appSettings of the web.config. I changed the code to use `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("CdnBaseHref")` because I wanted to be able to update the URL once the app was deployed via the Azure portal.

However, updating the URL does not cause the app startup code to run again, so I have one piece of the code using the updated setting, and the startup code still using the old setting, which of course breaks everything.

How can I cause each role instance to re-run the startup code when this setting has been updated?

Comment: How exactly is the startup code being invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. Changing the role configuration settings doesn't restart app domain, which enables you to change application behavior (code that depends on configuration) on the fly without hampering the app domain.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if I read a configuration on application_start for exemple, and store it in a static variable, it will never be updated when I change the config? Thats right?

Comment: Right, until the static variable itself is flushed automatically. To update the static variable with the changed config value, you may want to have an server side utility (may be a mvc/web api controller) that will set the static variable as null.

Answer (score 1):

You can register to listen for `RoleEnvironment.Changing Event` that gets triggered when a config change will happen. When you detect this event you can "refresh" your static variables with the new values. You can read more details on the [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx#Anchor_1). There is also `RoleEnvironment.Changed Event` that will get trigerred after the change. These events can be registered in the `OnStart()` method of the worker role.